# How to preg_replace div class in single quotes?

Tags: preg-replace

Two guys here helped me to solve my PHP problems (thanks very much to them),but I have one more

I want to preg_replace a div class + ID which has single quotes.

I'm not a programmer so excuse my poor description

Thanks in advance
Andrei

Comment: Can you give a copy and paste of an example of the text you're dealing with? It's always simpler to work with a real example. Some context helps too - are you wanting to run it against some random page from the internet (so the pattern would need to be very flexible) or a known website?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following div:

```
$html="<div class='divclass' id='divid'></div>";
```

In order to get class use: `preg_match("/(?<=class\=\')\w+(?<!\')/",$html,$match);`

In order to get id use: `preg_match("/(?<=id\=\')\w+(?<!\')/",$html,$match);`